# Últimamente he tenido problemas para insertar una imagen en un label de tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, imagen

Estoy obteniendo este error:

```
  File "C:\Users\UserLENOVO\Documents\FER\--Program--\Dice\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    test=Label(window, image='imagen').pack()
  File "C:\Users\UserLENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3143, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\UserLENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2567, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "imagen" doesn't exist
```

Este es mi código:

```
    from tkinter import*
    window = Tk()
    window.title("TEST")
    imagen=PhotoImage(r'C:\Users\UserLENOVO\Documents\FER\--Program--\Dice\four.png')
    test=Label(window, image='imagen').pack()
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos problemas:

1. El constructor de [PhotoImage](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) recibe el nombre del archivo a leer en su parámetro `file`, que **no** es el primero. Hay que pasárselo por nombre:

   ```
    imagen = PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\UserLENOVO\Documents\FER\--Program--\Dice\four.png')
   ```
2. Al constructor de Label tenés que pasarle la *imagen* deseada (el objeto PhotoImage), no el *nombre* de la variable que la guarda. Es decir, las comillas no van:

   ```
    test = Label(window, image=imagen).pack()
   ```

Con esos dos cambios debe funcionar.